# Flex column series not displaying column

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I am having a column series with two columns side by side.

```
<mx:ColumnSeries xField="period" yField="FirstCalls" displayName="1st calls" />
<mx:ColumnSeries xField="period" yField="SecondCalls" displayName="2nd calls"/>
```

I am facing a problem here. If the 'FirstCalls' field used in the first series is more than some 4000 then it is not displaying column. I think my chart is using a fixed ratio for the height, i donno why. the height of the column chart is small, hence I should display the first calls for 27000 as well as 400 also in a ratio. Please help, is there any property which will set the height ratio, like the columnWidthRatio.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you provide a runnable sample w/ some sample data to demo the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys. It was a mistake from my side only. I had put the value '4000' as maximum in the vertical axis.